# Is there a way to import a Scala file from a meta project definition into the project definition?

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm using Caliban it comes with a plugin. Plugin version is the same as the library versions.
So I'm trying to define this version in one place only.

I've created a project/project/Versions.scala with the `object Version { val calibanVersion = "1.4.1" }`

I can use it in project/plugins.sbt so all is good here.

But I would like to use in my project/Dependencies.scala as well and I cannot find a way to import it.